# Updates in Mongo Db

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

I have a use case where  a  spring  job(@Scheduled fixedDelay) runs against a mongo collection and process some of the documents.In current state the job
is triggered only from one jvm.How ever we want to run the job from multiple  jvms for availability . We are not looking for  both the jobs  to run in parallel but in case
a jvm goes down other one should execute.We are planning to update all documents to a 'processing' state so  only one of the job will have access to these documents
The question I have is what will happen if  two jobs  get triggered at the same ?.Both   jobs will select the same records in this case but how  can we identify the job that got the write lock
and updated the documents to processing status.

Answer (score 0):

Its a case of distributed transaction. If you still have this problem - I'd speculate if you use spring-data with Mongo, Hibernate would be able to invalidate the data in one of the JVM contexts when data has changed. And then you'd get and error in that JVM.